# Modal show up but could not see the content

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

This is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">text</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Done!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my link:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Text</a>
```

When I click to the button the modal is activating but I cannot see anything from it just the screen got darker.

Could you please help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to guess but likely a z-index issue. Where the dulling background is sufficiently high but your modal itself is not.

Comment: Should I copy some settings from my bootstrap css? I use the default btw.

Comment: Might be more helpful 

Comment: .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}

Comment: You can try to set the z-index: 9999.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of console error? I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: z-index: 9999 did not helped :( 

I don't get console error. I just don't see the content. I noticed that the modal is activated becouse the screen got darker.

Comment: Possible to get a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://imgur.com/rzrx8uN

Comment: you are trying to load the remote content into the modal, right?

Comment: What does it mean? I have a modal with fixed text. My task is to create modal which is showing up after a link click.

Answer (score 0):

First you need show button, then module code:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Test</a>



    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">text</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Done!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But in my case all works, if I correct understand your question.